# SSL renegotiation workflow for HTTP

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, nio

I have a HTTP server with runs with HTTP and HTTPS, written using Javas NIO and SSL libraries. In HTTPS mode it can communicate with or without the client certificate. However, I would like to perform renegotiation. Here the client will connect with HTTPS, browse resources and then when they hit a highly secure resource the server challenges the client for its certificate. I have been having a few problems with this and need to know what the workflow should be. Here is what I have observed with both IE 9 and Chrome.

1) When the client requests the secure resource, I respond to the HTTP request in full. I then challenge the client for their cert upon completion with

```
engine.setNeedClientAuth(true);  
engine.beginHandshake();
```

The result is a TCP FIN from the client (it closes its side of the connection), and the renegotiation fails.

2) When the client requests the secure resource, I challenge for the cert before responding. In this scenario the exchange occurs, both browsers will popup a request for the cert, however as soon as it pops up the prompt a TCP FIN is sent from the client and renegotiation terminates. The client then sends another request which eventually has the certificate, at times I have to challenge twice.

So my question here is, what is supposed to happen? Is the initial browser connection supposed to remain open, or is termination like this normal?

**NOTE:** Another very interesting observation here is that, in scenario 2, when the browser closes the TCP connection, it then reconnects after you choose the certificate. It does not however repost the request, it just sits there and expects the server to respond? In NIO terminology its sits waiting on an OP_READ, which means there is no data on the socket input buffer. Do the browsers expect a response to the original message that it terminated the connection for??

Strange that there is absolutely no documentation or a specification for this workflow, yet for all the browsers I've tested they seem to follow this workflow.

Answer (score 1):

(1) is insecure and therefore pointless to discuss further. You've already leaked the information before you even ask for the credentials.

(2) is the correct way to do this. The client shouldn't be closing the connection *if* it is configured to allow renegotiation. Due to an SSL security problem last year or so there was temporarily a phase where SSL renegotiation was disallowed by default. You may be running into this. In that case you should be issuing an HTTP redirect first, and closing the connection at your end to force the client to use a new connection, and the new connection should ask for a client certificate. How you arrange that in your code is up to you.

Comment: The initial close is actually part of the workflow, this is done so that the browser can popup a dialog for the client to choose the SSL certificate, even with RFC 5746 compliant negotiations. When client connects again it does a normal SSL handshake, but does not exchange the certificate, the server must challenge for the certificate with a second SSL hello request. On this, the third negotiation, the certificate is exchanged.

Comment: That won't work if the client won't renegotiate, unless there is another close between the second connection and the challenge.